# Eigen - reshape a vector to matrix

Tags: c++, reshape, eigen

I am trying to reshape a vector to a matrix, but getting the following error

```
unsigned int Nx     = 8;
unsigned int Ny     = 7;
Eigen::VectorXi G_temp = Eigen::VectorXi::LinSpaced((Nx + 2) * (Ny + 2),0,(Nx + 2) * (Ny + 2)-1);
Eigen::MatrixXd G = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>(G_temp.data(),Nx+2, Ny+2); // error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>'
```

I followed what is written [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReshapeSlicing.html), but I do not understand the way I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion from integer-valued to double-valued expressions in Eigen. Either just use `VectorXd` for `G_temp` (and the `LinSpaced` expression):

```
Eigen::VectorXd G_temp = Eigen::VectorXd::LinSpaced((Nx + 2) * (Ny + 2),0,(Nx + 2) * (Ny + 2)-1);
```

Or use a `MatrixXi`-Map and `.cast<double>()` the result before assigning it to `G`.

```
Eigen::MatrixXd G = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXi>(G_temp.data(),Nx+2, Ny+2).cast<double>();
```

To avoid any temporary, you can also allocate a `MatrixXd` and directly assign the proper values inside:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd G(Nx+2, Ny+2); // allocate matrix
// set values in-place:
Eigen::VectorXd::Map(G.data(), (Nx + 2) * (Ny + 2)).setLinSpaced(0,(Nx + 2) * (Ny + 2)-1);
```

Or with the master/3.4 branch:

```
G.reshaped().setLinSpaced(0,(Nx + 2) * (Ny + 2)-1);
```